# Symfony: How to save record with undefined foreign key record

Tags: symfony1, symfony-1.4

For example, Comment table has foreign key at Author table. How do I create a new author record when I save a new comment? e.g.: Comment: id = 1, author_id = [newly generated id associated with author table], content = "this is a new comment". Author: id = 1, author_name = [newly generated author name].

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This has nothing to do with Symfony. I assume you're using Doctrine, am I right? Well, all you have to do is to create `Comment` and `Author` objects:

```
$author = new Author();
$author->setName('Crozin');

$comment = new Comment();
$comment->setAuthor($author);
$comment->setContent('This is my first comment!');

$comment->save();
```

Doctrine should recognize that you're using two brand new objects that aren't persisted in database and thus both object will be inserted.

Comment: Gotta lover symfony Table model classes to handle all of this.

Comment: Yes I'm using Doctrine. How do I first make sure that 'Crozin' isn't already in the table? Thanks.

Comment: @Yzmir Ramirez: Actually Doctrine1.2 really isn't as good as you could think of it. @whamsicore: Well, you have to count occurrences of `Crozin` in database. [Here's an example of how to do that](http://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/orm/1.2/docs/manual/data-hydrators/en#core-hydration-methods:single-scalar)

Comment: This is a little off topic, but what don't you like about Doctrine 1.2? Do you think Propel is better?

Comment: Things that sucks in Doctrine **1.2** 1. It uses [ActiveRecord pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ActiveRecord) which is really bad in my opinion as it breaks [Single responsibility principle](http://goo.gl/Kl22) (one of the most important thing in whole OOP). 2. It forces you to write a code that strongly depends on Doctrine. 3. It's a way too magical. 4. For a slightly more advanced projects it's just too slow. 5. It's extremely hard to make it works transparently. Thankfully Doctrine2 improved most of that. PS. I've never thought about Propel as a better ORM. ;)